# TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY and nonblocking sockets

Tags: posix, nonblocking, eintr

Should I use `TEMP_FAILURE_RETRY` to surround library calls (which can fail and set errno to EINTR) on nonblocking sockets?

Comment: What a stunning lack of context. Perhaps some information on operating system, programming language, the issue you're trying to address, what you've already tried.... ?

Comment: On purpose I didn't add details. It's a question on specs, and POSIX specs should not vary upon my OS. And if they do, I'd like to know all the possibilities (win, linux, bsd, mac). At most, I forgot to underline that by system calls I mean those that can fail and set EINTR. Edited.

Comment: you'll get more people viewing this question if you add better tags, posix and nonblocking have very few questions.

Comment: unfortunately I cannot create yet new tags.